# Hiding symbols from static library when building an Android project with Clang as compiler

Tags: android, clang, static-libraries, symbols

Hiding symbols when gcc is used as compiler can be done using the --exclude-libs option.

A working example:

My Application.mk file looks like this:

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_STL=c++_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-21
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

The following line in the Android.mk file does the job:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--exclude-libs=library.a
```

If I remove the following line from the Application.mk file

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
```

I believe Clang is used as the default compiler, which doesn't seem to have an --exclude-libs option, so symbols from library.a are not hidden anymore.

Is there a Clang equivalent to the gcc --exclude-libs option?

I have already tried the suggestion at the following link

http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2013-June/030376.html

but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Modifying the source code and making use of Clang's LTO Visibility property is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to is correct. `--exclude-libs` is a linker option, and even when you compile with Clang, GCC is still used for linking. From the NDK documentation:

> GCC binaries are also included, because Clang relies on the same assembler, linker, headers, libraries included in the GCC distribution.

So, `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--exclude-libs,library.a` should work (note the `,` instead of `=`). I have verified that it does work in a CMake project (which uses slightly different syntax, but sets the exact same linker option).

The most likely reason why this isn't working for you is that the actual filename of your archive is something other than `library.a` (e.g. it might be `liblibrary.a` or something similar).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The name of the library is not actually library.a. This was chosen just for the purpose of this example. So the example I've given, with the actual library filename works, but only if I set the NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=4.9.

Comment: And what if you set it to `clang` ?

Comment: I tried using a CMake project as well, with the following command in the CMakeLists.txt file: set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl -exclude-libs,ALL"). This wasn't successful. Could you please share the flags that you set in the CMake project?

Comment: That's the same option I'm setting. I've also verified that it works when using `ndkBuild` instead of `cmake`. Are you sure that you're inspecting the right .so file (i.e. the one that got packaged into the APK, and not some intermediate version)?

Comment: Except of course that it should be `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`, not `-Wl -exclude-libs,ALL`.

Comment: Brilliant. Now it works using both `ndkBuild` and `cmake` and the problems were indeed `,` instead of `=` and respectively `-Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL` instead of `-Wl -exclude-libs,ALL`. Thanks a lot